# Write javascript variables directly or load via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, echo

We have a one page application that needs to load about 100 user specific data points into Javascript variables that are not required for the initial painting of the page.

Is it better to load the variables while creating the dynamic page and "write" them to Javascript (using PHP echo or ASP response.write), or first load the page and then load the data using an AJAX call?

I am aware that using an AJAX call will allow painting the page quicker but are there any other advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: If the data not needed for initial render & if it possible to defer the loading of the data(ie: you can execute JavaScript in the page), then the data is not required to be returned in the HTML document itself. Once you have loaded the HTML document, the data can be requested. It can be returned in the format that you would feel comfortable. ie: you can return the data as JSON & generate the HTML in the client. Or you can return the HTML itself & simply render it in the client. It is upto you.

Comment: I do not know why this question is closed. At least I know that the content of the question is not related to the linked question.

Comment: @Tamil Did you read the accepted answer in the linked duplicate? The long list of possible ways to pass data with a list of **pros and cons** for each? Sounds *very related* to me.

Comment: @deceze, This question is not about how to transfer data from server(PHP) to client(JavaScript). OP already knows how to transfer data from server to client. The question is more about when to do that for his/her specific scenario. If you read my first comment, you will see what is the question is about.

Comment: I agree with @deceze. They ask if loading the vars by rendering them in the page from start or getting them later is preferable. Hundreds of vars does not make a difference. Hundreds of Ks of vars, might. you can lso load them at the end of the page if you wish. The question can also be closed as "opinion seeking"